# Why are my numbers coming out negative for results of the first 100000 squares?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I have to create a code that displays the squares of the first 100000 numbers and measure the amount of time the program takes to display each number. During my results, the numbers sometimes go negative and then go positive again. Why is this? How should I change my code so that my results are not negative? (This does not happen with the first 1000 square numbers or 10000).

```
package assignment.pkg5;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class LoopsLab1000001b {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long time_start, time_finish;
        time_start = time();

        int count = 1;
        while (count <= 100000) {
            System.out.println(count * count);
            count++;
        }

        time_finish = time();

        System.out.println(time_finish - time_start + " milli seconds");

    }

    public static long time() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        return cal.getTimeInMillis();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing int count = 1 ; to long count = 1 ;

Comment: going negative --> positive --> negative is the tale-tell sign of an overflow. You probably are getting a really large number and overflowing the int or long type. My bet is the int.

Comment: I will try changing it to long.  (EDIT: Thank you so much! It worked, it was probably an overflow).

Comment: @blue1artic in Java, int is signed, meaning the most significant bit tells if the number is negative or positive. So as your number grew and overflowed, you are swapping the most significant bit from 0 --> 1 --> 0 --> 1, etc, depending on what number it was. This is why you get the alternating negative --> positive --> negative, etc.

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem (you also found the answer): I recommend you `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead of that `Calendar` usage. It is more efficient for this particular problem.

Comment: @powerMock Thank you for the suggestion, I am aware of the     System.currentTimeMillis() method, my instructor told us we should use the     Calendar method. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @powerMock [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) should be faster *and* more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer overflow. See [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), and specifically:

> In some situations, a program may make the assumption that a variable
>   always contains a positive value. If the variable has a signed integer
>   type, an overflow can cause its value to wrap and become negative.
>   This overflow violates the program's assumption and may lead to
>   unintended behavior.